# Find a text in a word table and add a character to the first cell of the same row

Tags: ms-word

i have a table in word with a constant number of columns, and a variable number of rows. I need a sub procedure to search for an specific text in the table (let's say "123"), and then add a character (let's say "*") to the text in the first cell of the same row where the text is. If this cell had the text "abc", the result will be "*abc".

This is what i've tried, without success:

Sub EliminarAcreditacion()

```
With ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).Find
    .Text = "NAC"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute
End With
With Selection
    .Collapse wdCollapseStart
    .Find.Execute
    .MoveLeft Unit:=wdCell, Count:=5
    .InsertBefore "+"
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
End With
```

End Sub

Thank you very much for your help,

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "NAC"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
      .Rows(1).Range.InsertBefore "*"
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```